# how to schedule a future task in different time zone in Perl?

Tags: perl, datetime, timezone, localtime

I have gone through a lot of answers, and none of them seems to solve my problem. I want to run a Perl script from New York to schedule a task on a computer in some other time zone, say Los Angeles (or any other time zone). The user who runs the script will have the option to enter the date/time and time zone.

Example:

```
perl script.pl -action reboot LAHost.com 2014/012/12 15:00:00 'America/Los_Angeles'
```

This script should schedule reboot on LAHost.com computer at 3pm local time in Los Angeles.

Could anyone help me find a way to do this in perl using DateTime or any other built-in functions?

I am new to programming and currently learning Perl. So please excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question appears be

> *How do I convert a date and time in a specified time zone to local time?*

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $date = '2014/012/12';
my $time = '15:00:00';
my $tz   = 'America/Los_Angeles';

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S',
   time_zone => $tz,
   on_error  => 'croak',
);

my $dt = $format->parse_datetime("$date $time");
$dt->set_time_zone('local');

print $format->format_datetime($dt), "\n";
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for; but since I didn't have the time to wait for an answer, I figured out a way which seemed to work for me, though I'm not sure if this is a best way:

my $timeZone="Europe/London";
my $dateTime = DateTime->new(year => $year, month => $month,
                day => $day, hour => $hour, minute => $minute,
                second => $second, time_zone => $timeZone);

I schedule an action in London time with "Europe/London" timezone set, kept an eye on London clock and at the right London time, the action was performed.

Thank you for showing me a different approach.

Comment: @Kaji Lama, Your deleted answer is equivalent to mine except you don't have to roll out your own parser if you use D::F::Strptime.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $timeZone="Europe/London";
my $dateTime = DateTime->new(year => $year, month => $month,
                day => $day, hour => $hour, minute => $minute,
                second => $second, time_zone => $timeZone);
```